# Excel dates formats

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-format

When users enter a date in Excel using this format `19.03.2013`, I need the cell to automatically change the format to Wed 19 Mar'14.

I copied dates(column C & D) from MS Project. I am getting error message when trying to use the formula `DATEVALUE`.

Maybe while copying the dates from MS Project Excel is considering the date as text and thus I am getting error message.

Any advice?

PS: sorry, I am unable to add image in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/format-a-date-the-way-you-want-HA102809474.aspx)...This might help you...

Steps:

1. Select the cells you want to format.
2. Press CTRL+1.
3. In the Format Cells box, click the Number tab.
4. In the Category list, click Date.
5. Under Type, pick a date format. Your format will preview in the Sample box with the first date in your data.
   Note: Date formats that begin with an asterisk (*) will change if you change the regional date and time settings in Control Panel. Formats without an asterisk won’t change.
6. If you want to use a date format based on how another language displays dates, pick the language under Locale (location),

Comment: You are welcome... Feel free to visit www.systemadminguide.wordpress.com for Server Tech stuffs

Comment: Please include the relevant details in your answer. Otherwise, you might as well link LMGTFY.

Comment: @DanielB, Relevant details in the sense?? The correct answer is there in the link..

Comment: [How to answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer): “Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.”

Comment: @DanielB, Done...Hope that's enough..